# javascript google map markers icon image change

Tags: javascript, google-maps-markers

I am adding markers in a custom map that i have created using google map .In add marker function i added the code and all the marker are getting displayed with default marker image.

So i thought lets change the default image of the marker so i added two line

//image line 1 and 2 ... please see code below

```
 var image = 'news2.png';    //image line 1

  // create the marker for that place
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
   position: myLatlng,
  icon: image,   //image line 2
title: place.place_name + ', '+ place.admin_name1
 });
```

but the marker are gone after adding these two line i dont know why.

with this code the image news2.png i stored in js directory in which the java script file is present with the code written above

i stored the image in img directory and used img/news.png in //image line 1 but still not markers are visible.

I removethese two line , all markers come back .

please help what wrong i am doing in changing the image of marker. thanks

Comment: Check the console, you will figure out what path is being used for the image and then fix it.

Comment: @adam  console on developer panel in chrome ? how can i check the path

Comment: Check if the path isn't returning 404 header. Either via Network tab or console

Comment: @adam Yes it is giving 404  not found. it is converting the path string in url... how to give directory path as string

Answer (score 0):

> `icon    Type:  string|Icon|Symbol`
>
> Icon for the foreground. If a string is provided, it is treated as though it were an Icon with the string as url.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#MarkerOptions

Have you tried using an absolute URL? I don't know if the API supports relative paths.

Comment: yes u r right, it is converting the path string in url... how to give directory path as string

Comment: Could you tell us what URL you're currently getting and what URL it is you would like to get?

Comment: zzhttp://map/public/js/news2.png 404 (Not Found) this is what is showing on console now my javascript is in folder map/public/js  and news2.png also is in folder map/public/js   what path i should give currently i am giving    image : "/public/js/news2.png" .  zz i added in start  here just to stop it to convert to link

Comment: It seems you need to provide a full URL. e.g. www.example.com/map/public/js/news.png

Comment: the folders are in my local harddrive so what should i put instead of www.example.com ,    or more general question how to use local hardrive png file  as google marker image

Comment: You can try using the full path of the file on your filesystem. It would end up looking something like this: `file:///Users/name/my/files/website/map/public/...`

Comment: its saying Not allowed to load local resource: file:///home/username/vhosts/map/public/js/news2.png   , i hope we cannot do what i am trying. I ll use online icon i hope.   Thanks for the help